# facebook C# sdk can't get authenticated

Tags: facebook-c#-sdk

I can't get authenticated. I click the login button, I enter username and password, but still the FacebookWebcontext.Current is like this:
[image]

So what is the problem, why doesn't it authenticate. is there a way to see what is the problem? What settings are wrong, or if facebook refused to issue the authentication for the app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

checkout the "samples" folder from the source code, for examples.

Comment: which version did u try it. i have updated all the samples for v5.2, could you try those ones instead